# Spring bootをゼロから学ぶのに最適な教材は？

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring

web開発未経験です

日本語ではなく英語でも可です

単なるハウツーにとどまらず、Spring Frameworkそのものを深く理解したいです

Comment: このサイトでは主観的な答えを促す質問や長々とした議論が必要になるような質問はは避けて下さい。詳しくは[ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)をご参照下さい。この手の質問は[チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ja.stackoverflow.com)（または[英語のStackOverflowのチャット](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/?tab=site&host=stackoverflow.com)）で聞くほうが適切です。

Answer (score 0):

個人的なご意見としてご理解ください。
日本語を中心としてお話します。
（英語の文章は、固有の単語が多く、初学者には固有単語の見分けが難しいと思っています。）

初学習におすすめなのはこちらです。
[プロになるためのSpring入門](https://amzn.asia/d/1Ri3Tu1)
SpringBootとSpringの違いから、SpringSecurity、テストにも触れられています。
Tymeleafを使ったWebサイト開発であれば、こちらの一冊で基本的な部分はマスターできるかと思います。
ただ、セッション管理やセキュリティ周りについては詳しい記述が弱いと感じています。

合わせて、Web開発未経験ということで、
セッション管理・認証について基本的な部分を勉強するかと良いと思います。
（ログインしているユーザーに合わせたコンテンツ管理には必須です。）

[体系的に学ぶ 安全なWebアプリケーションの作り方](https://amzn.asia/d/2Uj7dgy)
こういった本で基礎的な部分を学ぶと良いかと思います。

英語の書籍については知識が無いため、他の方が紹介していただけることを願います。
基本的にはSpringの公式ドキュメントがアーキテクチャについて説明を行なっているため、そちらをしっかりと読むことで、Springへの理解が深まるかと思います。
[Spring公式ドキュメント（日本語版）](https://spring.pleiades.io)

また、Spring自体はServletとTomcatが内蔵されているため、
どこまで詳しく学びたいかにもよりますが、そちらについても追々学習を行うと良いのでは無いでしょうか。

以上、参考になれば幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

Udemyの講座「Spring Boot 3, Spring 6 & Hibernate for Beginners」(講師:Chadさん)がとても素晴らしいです！ぜひ試してみてください！